# Running scheduled jobs on Rundeck in the cloud

Tags: cloud, instance, jobs, execution, rundeck

I have scheduled rundeck jobs to run on various server instances in the cloud and the instances are referenced by instance ID in the job. The problem is that when a instance is reprovisioned the Rundeck job fails because the instance now has a new ID. Anybody have a solution to the issue?

Comment: Could you elaborate? Any job definition example to understand the question? Maybe you need to store the id on a data value to work https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ao2SvpspWl4

Comment: thanks for you response. To elaborate, in the job definition under tab 'nodes' i have defined a 'node filter' which is the server instance (tag or ID) so that the job will execute the 'workflow' command on the server instance i have defined. The problem is that the (tag or ID) id only valid until the server instance is reprovisioned. the tag or ID is different after the instance is reprovisioned and therefore the Rundeck job fails as it has a invalid tag or ID configured. Hope this helps?

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is to use the data passing feature in this order: 1) create a provide your instance 2) get the new id (maybe via api with your "cloud provider") and 3) use that id for anything.

I leave a basic example/fake job definition to test:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='current_node' value='9272c5fbfdd2ed332592ab565318c55d' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>e7e973aa-987d-40c2-8883-be00191113cd</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>CloudJob</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <description>Reprovisioning the instance. Later catch the new id. This step have an log filter attach to get the id and save it on data value (using a regex).</description>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <plugins>
          <LogFilter type='key-value-data'>
            <config>
              <invalidKeyPattern>\s|\$|\{|\}|\\</invalidKeyPattern>
              <logData>true</logData>
              <regex>^(id)\s*:\s*(.+)$</regex>
            </config>
          </LogFilter>
        </plugins>
        <script><![CDATA[# reprovisioning simulation
echo "current instance id:@option.current_node@"
echo "provisioning the instance..."
sleep 3
echo "instance reprovisioned..."

# in this part you must caught the new id (maybe via cloud provider api?)
echo "id:9d42d17404ec17b41861879305fd454b" # new id
echo "have a nice day :-)"]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
      <command>
        <description>now you can do anything with new id (stored at ${data.id} option</description>
        <exec>echo "the new id is ${data.id}"</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>e7e973aa-987d-40c2-8883-be00191113cd</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

[Here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/log-filters/key-value-data.html#key-value-data) you can see more information about key-value log filter use. And [here](https://youtu.be/ao2SvpspWl4?t=176) a good example about data passing feature.